# Loading table in the particular order

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

I have to load big table (over > 2 TB) from SQL Server 2008 R2 to Oracle Exadata using SSIS. Is it possible to load it in particular order (based on 1 or two columns)?

Comment: It's possible to control the order in which records are passed between the two dbs, but this may not be the order Oracle chooses to store the records in.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Exadata works better (faster) if you load data in particular order (in most cases - primary/foreign keys), due to Storage Indexes.

Comment: Within your data flow you can use a SQL command to return the source data in the required order.  Using the *OLE DB* or *ADO NET* Sources look for the *Data access mode* dropdown.

Comment: Is the big table in SQL Server stored as a clustered index in the required order, or will it have to be sorted? Is this a one-time or a recurring operation?

Comment: Yes, as clustered index in the required order.

Comment: In that case, the answer by SebTHU should work well. Put the ORDER BY clause into the query in the data source. SQL Server won't have to do a massive sort and SSIS can process them in the required sequence.

Comment: And after it I have certainty that I write it in the same order in Oracle disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If loading in order is a requirement, definitely put the ORDER BY into the query in the Data Source (probably OLEDB Source, if your source is SQL2008R2).  This lets the database engine do the work.

The SSIS Sort data transformation is a performance bottleneck, which tries to operate in memory and necessarily has to load the entire dataset before outputting any rows.  With the volume of data you're talking about, performance will be terrible.

Comment: I don't have enough RAMs to do it (it's over 1 bilion of records). Can I utilized clustered index?

Comment: If the ORDER BY is in the query, then *server* RAM/tempdb space will be the limiting factor.  Is the server really running out of RAM?  If you're not sorting within your SSIS package, and are still running out of memory, there may be a fully-blocking component elsewhere in your package, forcing your client (dev) machine to load the entire dataset.  See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx

Comment: It'll be memory on the local PC while using BIDS (et.al.) I would guess?

Comment: It is the local machine that runs SSIS during dev in BIDS, of course.  But if the package is wholly non-blocking (no blocking components), the local SSIS process only has to load one buffer of the dataset into memory at a time, before writing it out and loading the next one.  Even this can cause problems, esp. if you have insufficient memory (e.g. 4Gb) on your dev machine.  But a blocking component will force SSIS (as you say, the local machine) to load the entire dataset before releasing it, which may be impossible.